# Load GeoTIFF band value into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geotiff-tiff, vectorization, raster2pgsql

I am trying to upload a geoTIFF file into my PostGIS database. Using raster2psql, it works.

```
raster2pgsql -I -C -M *.tif -F -t auto mytablename > mytable.sql
psql -d mydatabase -f mytable.sql
```

However, my datatable is not what I expect it to be.

I get:

```
rid | rast | filename 
----+------+----------
 1    01000001000F1111111111813F0F111111111181BF00000000008066C0FAFFFFFFFF7F564000000000000000000000000000000000E61000001E001E006AFDFF7FFFFDFF7... filename.tif
```

What I want is:

```
rid | geometry | value | filename
 1    0100AF...   12.3   filename.tif
```

Where geometry is the hex code associated, and the value is the band value from the raster.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, PostGIS stores raster in bigger objects, not tile-wise. So your one line contains multiple raster cells, which you can see in any GIS program. Have you tried to use `-t <a>x<b>`, where a and b are the size of your raster cells? At least I've done that once and the corresponding value should be accessible with `ST_Value`. Check out the [documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Value.html) for examples.